# Recycleview PagerSnapHelper scrolling distance

Tags: android, scroll, pagersnaphelper

How can I customize scroll distance for PagerSnapHelper so that Recycleview scrolling will be with current visible item height .

```
 binding.videoTrendsRecycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            binding.videoTrendsRecycle.setMediaObjects(videosResponse.getVideosResponseArrayList());
                            SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
                            snapHelper.findTargetSnapPosition(mLayoutManager, 0, 1000);
                            binding.videoTrendsRecycle.setOnFlingListener(null);
                            snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.videoTrendsRecycle);
           VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter adapter = new VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter(videosResponse.getVideosResponseArrayList(), initGlide(context), context);
```